# How do I create a mount point on my Android TV box?

Tags: android, mount, nas

I am trying to creat a mount point on my Android TV box, I issue the mount command and I get the error "/etc/fstab does not exist"   how do I get around this?

I know this can be done, because I can see a mount already on my android TV to my other NAS box.   My problem is no one can remember making this mount point, or how it could have been done.

Comment: Are you SSHing to your Android TV box?

Comment: Yes using SSH to set up the mount points

Comment: maybe your `fstab` is called `/etc/vold.fstab`